# how to override the heading on rails new/edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

using Rails 3, Ruby 1.9, with bootstrap and jQuery.

In my _form.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form_for(@system_cat, :html => {:class => "form form-horizontal system-cat"}) do |f| %>
```

application.html.erb has:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>System Catalog</title>
  .
  .
  .
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the page ends up with:

```
.
.
.
<body>
  <h1>New system_cat</h1>
.
.
.
```

Everything works fine, I would just like to replace the 'New system_cat' heading, same for the edit page which uses the same _form.html.erb file - it ends up with 'Edit system_cat'.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm fully clear; are you aware that those titles are contained in the `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` files? You can simply edit those files and replace the text in the `<h1>` tag. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: the <h1> tag is being automatically generated, I didn't put it there but I'll put one in, just figured there was some way to tell form_for what to put in the heading

Comment: @cordii - `form_for` does not generate such a heading, it has to be created somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah the titles are automatically generated in the `new` and `edit` html.erb files, when you generate the views (such as when you do `rails g scaffold...`). Basically think of it like this; the `_form.html.erb` doesn't (or shouldn't) care whether its being called from an edit or new action. Its the `new` and `edit` files, which call that partial, that should be responsible for setting general, action-specific, things like the title and such.

Comment: LOL, I didn't even look in new.html.erb and edit.html.erb since all the work I've been doing dealt with the form, hahaha.... duh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is partially a followup to the comments discussion*

As I wrote in the comments, the titles you refer to are actually (or at least, **should** be) in the specific action view files for new and edit (So `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`). If you look at those files, they are actually calling your `_form.html.erb` partial. For example, this is what one of my `new.html.erb` looks like:

```
<h2>Add Device</h2>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

And the `edit.html.erb` looks like:

```
<h2>Edit Device</h2>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

Same thing; different title.

BroiSatse answer is good and will work, but my concern would be putting too much action-specific logic in your partials. As BroiSatse noted, sometimes its necessary to do something like that on occasion, but if you can avoid it, it usually makes for much cleaner code. So an alternative would be to simply edit the titles in those action view files instead.

As I wrote in the comments, the `_form.html.erb` doesn't (or shouldn't) care whether its being called from an edit or new action. Its the new and edit files, which call that partial, that should be responsible for setting general, action-specific, things like the title and such.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
  <h1><%= @system_cat.new_record? ? 'New' : 'Edit' %> system_cat</h1>
```

Comment: Good old method.Very nice!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something; is there a reason you would want to do that, when you could simply set the title appropriately in either the `edit` or `new` html.erb files?

Comment: In this case there's most likely not. However this can be used within the partial, which then can be used in `new` , `edit` and any other action or view.

Comment: thanks for this @BroiSatse I didn't use it on the system_cat form, but I did use it for another form I'm building and it works great!